# Build time for makefile recipe

Tags: shell, unix, makefile, gnu-make

I want to caluclate time spent for each recipe in makefile

```
SYS_TIME = $(shell date)
SUBDIRS = a b c d

.PHONY = default

default:
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); \
    do \
       $(eval ST = $(SYS_TIME)) \
       $(MAKE) -C FOLD=$$dir; \
       $(eval ET = $(SYS_TIME))
       echo "time spent  =   $(ST) - $(ET) "
   done; \
```

result should look like:

> time spent  = 1:35
>
> time spent  = 2:23
>
> time spent  = 10:59
>
> time spent  = 5:35

it signify 1 minute 35 sec for first and same for others

or some other alternative for **$(shell date)**

Comment: Please show us your work. Also take for instance a simple makefile specifying a debug build option and a release build option. running the debug build and the release afterwards might make the release build seem to run very fast. One recipe can influence other recipes build time.

Comment: Side note: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6966877/4153464 This might be what you're looking for. It won't interpret your makefile but its likely close enough

Comment: @Work of Artiz  in this case i have only one recipe. Other build thing i am not getting can you more specify it.

Comment: _Important_ to know: _Make_ will expand the entire recipe (which is stored as a single recursively expanded variable) as the first step in working out what to pass to the shell. It then runs each line of the expansion one-by-one, each in a separate shell invocation. The upshot of this is that both of your `$(eval...)`s will run at expansion time, before the shell gets to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prefix your command lines with `time`, e.g.: `time $(MAKE) -C $$dir`.

Comment: later i will be redirecting time spent to a file

Comment: can you suggest some alternative for A := $(shell date)