# How to improve dependencies check speed with make

Tags: makefile

I have a project with about 1000 sources files.

Make takes about 5 seconds to check whether the project is up to date.

Is there any solution to improve this check? (Is C-Make more suitable for this kind of project?)

Comment: You mean the `--check-faster` option? The only--  No! Forget I said that! *There is no such option!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake uses Make, so using CMake probably won't help.

One thing you can try is find out whether disk I/O is the bottleneck. That seems likely if rerunning your `make` command is a lot faster than the initial run. To be sure, put the files on a memory-mapped filesystem (on Linux, I use [`/dev/shm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs); on Windows, I use [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk)).

You may also need to check whether your rules can be optimized. [GNU Make doesn't have any profiling built in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407048/makefile-profiling) to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of GNU make called [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) that includes a profiler.